# Unsubscribe link in email redirect to Vue.js landingpage

Tags: php, vue.js, unsubscribe

I'm working on the frontend for a Vuejs app with a PHP/Laravel backend. I have no PHP/Laravel or backend know-how.

I have to create a landingpage for clients to unsubscribe for after clicking the unsubscribe link.

- We have multiple newsletters.
- Unsubscribe link redirects to a Vuejs landingpage.
- User can then unsubscribe for some or all newsletter updates.

The problem now is:

I can't show them all the newsletters they're subscribed for without first having to login. We don't want them to log in.

- What data do I need from the backend to show the client all the newsletters they're subscribed for?
- How is this data implemented in the newsletter and or unsubscribe link?
- And how can I catch that data on the Vuejs frontend when they're redirected to the landingpage?

When they're are logged in, I make an api call to get a contactDetails object which has all the newsletters they're subsribed for. I then simply toggle that data when they unsubscribe and make a post request to update the contactDetails.

When they're not logged in, it obvioustly throws a 401 unauthorized error when fetching the contactDetails.

What's the best way to get this to work?

Frontend: Vuejs
Backend: Laravel

Comment: You could use a magic link in your newsletter, also known as [One-time password](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_password) to log in the user right away since the user is authenticated by having access to the email given that you verified it before.

Comment: Are there any security implications? Would it be better to do a combination of email and id with a hash secret? I have little backend knowledge how that works so could you explain that in detail?

Comment: Well, if somebody gets access to your inbox, I wouldn't consider it secure anymore.